# What are the IP ports to be opened to be able to order photos with iPhoto?

Tags: mac, networking, iphoto

I have made a book using pictures with iPhoto. When I try to order a copy of it there is a problem with the connexion. this is a quite secure network here. What are the IP ports to be opened to be able to order photos with iPhoto ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA27679?viewlocale=en_US) addresses photo sharing through iPhoto, which (although not in exact relation to your question) might be helpful.  Also, though iPhoto is not specifically listed, [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1629) is a list of "well known" ports used by Apple softwares.  I'm mostly ignorant about network protocols, but if I had to guess, I'd suspect that perhaps there's some HTTPS action going on when you try to place an order through iPhoto.  Those ports are listed in that second link.

Comment: Without data from Apple I would guess that it's a web service call.  Most likely on HTTPS or HTTP. (ports 443 or 80)